# What is a better practice: relative or absolute paths for css/js file includes?

Tags: html, css

Would you say it's better to have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

on any page that uses `style.css` or is it better to use relative paths, for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">
```

?

Comment: The first one is easier for browsers to understand.  the `..' convention isn't mandatory.

Comment: I would actually like to see this question re-opened.   I believe it's a valid question, and while answers may offer some opinions, isn't a programming approach to a solution always somewhat opinionated, as there are often multiple solutions?   I believe an open discussion as to the pros and cons of each method is appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the relative to root approach.  If you copy-n-paste code, you don't have to worry about having an incorrect path.

My vote:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Of course, [this guy](http://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/) makes a case for full URLs, but if you ever move your site to a different domain it could be a huge headache.  [This guy](http://www.freelancephp.co.uk/2013/04/20/why-web-developers-are-right-about-relative-urls/) thinks absolute URLs are a no-no, and takes on each argument.  I tend to side with the second.

Answer (score 2):

I would also vote for keeping my paths relative to the site's root.  My reasoning is that using this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

I always know that I'm pointing to the %root%/css folder.   I don't have to keep track of how many subfolders in I am, and calculate the right amount of ../ to traverse my way back to the origin.

I also just think it's cleaner to read.   My two cents.